# The uniqueness of minimal genus Seifert surfaces for knots in $S^3$.

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I was reading some materials about knots, some procedures inspired me to ask this question. Given a knot $K$ in $S^3$, one can use Seifert's algorithm to obtain a surface in $S^3$ whose boundary is $K$. Surfaces in $S^3$ with boundaries $K$ are not unique, you can isotopy or add a handle to such a surface to obtain another surface with identical boundary. The Seifert genus of $K$, denoted $g(K),$ is then defined to be the minimal genus of surfaces in $S^3$ whose boundaries are $K$.

It is natural to ask whether such minimal genus Seifert surfaces are unique. Specifically, let $F_1,F_2$ be two Seifert surfaces of $K$, such that $g(F_1)=g(F_2)=g(K)$. Can we isotopy $F_1$, rel boundary, to obtain $F_2$?
Thanks for any answer or reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, typically there are many non-isotopic minimal genus Seifert surfaces for a given knot $K$. These surfaces can be organized into a geometric object called the Kakimizu complex. For example Banks has provided examples where this complex is locally infinite:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.3831.pdf

In particular, these are examples of knots with infinitely many non-isotopic Seifert surfaces.

Comment: Nonuniqueness was known earlier, before Banks

Comment: Of course. I have no idea what the first reference is though.

Comment: At least W. R. Alford, "Complements of minimal spanning surfaces are not unique," Ann. of Math. 91 (1970) 419–424. For more references, see Kakimizu's 1992 paper.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely not the area of knot theory that I know best

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for your answers. I came to know that for a fibered knot $K$, its minimal genus Seifert surface is unique up to isotopy, any Seifert surface $F$ of $K$ that induces a fiberation of $S^3-N(K)$ over $S^1$, with $F$ a fiber, must be of minimal genus. This is my motivation to ask this.